# conflicting keybinding between terminal and vim

Tags: linux, vim, terminal, key-bindings

so I would like to use the same keybinding for my terminal and for my vim editor.
Example open new tab: Ctrl-t

---

is there a way to use a key to specify to which instance my binding will be applied.
example:

1. press f1 -> keybinding on vim
2. press f1 again -> keybinding on terminal

is this possible or I necessarily need to choose different keybinding in order to use them all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have different key bindings for Vim and for your terminal.  Vim doesn't read keyboard input independently of the terminal it lives in, it reads the keyboard *from* the terminal.  If you press a key sequence that has a meaning for the terminal, the terminal will apply whatever function corresponds to it, and it simply won't hand the sequence to Vim.